# Serializing and deserializing the object in different jvm instances

Tags: java, serialization

I have query that I was going through serialization in java please let me know if I open two instances of JVM , let say I open two different work spaces of eclipse in two different locations and in one work-space I have created the program to serialize the object in file having .ser extension and through another workspace I have created the program to deserialize the object by reading that .ser file .

Now please advise will that object get deserialized in different instance of JVM?  The question revolves around the fact that is object serialized and deserialized in the same instance of JVM is compulsorily one..!!

Comment: All that matters is you have the same code for the classes you want to deserialize. Otherwise serialization wouldn't be very useful because when you restart an application you have a different JVM instance.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Amazing man , hats off to you , Could you please post the code in which you can show the both the cases that will make understanding more clear

Comment: @user1582269 The best way to learn is to try it yourself. I don't see I can prove something is not a problem when I don't understand the source of the doubt.

Comment: Of course it works between different JVMs. It would be both useless and pointless otherwise. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @EJP so you mean to say that it works within different instances of JVM ..!!

Comment: There is need for you to tell me what I meant to say. It is perfectly clear already.

Comment: It is the same as JAVA says: write once run anywhere...
This is what the magic of JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is a process by which we can store the state of an object into any storage medium. We can store the state of the object into a file, into a database table etc. Deserialization is the opposite process of serialization where we retrieve the object back from the storage medium.

Eg1: Assume you have a Java bean object and its variables are having some values. Now you want to store this object into a file or into a database table.     This can be achieved using serialization. Now you can retrieve this object again from the file or database at any point of time when you need it. This can be achieved using deserialization.

```
**Serialization Example:**

Employee e = new Employee();
      e.name = "Reyan Ali";
      e.address = "Phokka Kuan, Ambehta Peer";

          e.SSN = 11122333;
          e.number = 101;
          try
          {
             FileOutputStream fileOut =
             new FileOutputStream("employee.ser");
             ObjectOutputStream out =
                                new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
             out.writeObject(e);
             out.close();
              fileOut.close();
          }catch(IOException i)
          {
              i.printStackTrace();
          }

**Deserializing an Object:**
The following DeserializeDemo program deserializes the Employee object created in the SerializeDemo program. Study the program and try to determine its output:



Employee e = null;
         try
         {
            FileInputStream fileIn =
                          new FileInputStream("employee.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            e = (Employee) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
        {
            System.out.println(.Employee class not found.);
            c.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Deserialized Employee...");
        System.out.println("Name: " + e.name);
        System.out.println("Address: " + e.address);
        System.out.println("SSN: " + e.SSN);
        System.out.println("Number: " + e.number);
```

Comment: ..cool man, But what if serilization happen inone instance and deserialization is done in another instance of JVM..!!

Comment: @EJP I have read that it won't work and this is my qyery also will it work..?

Comment: -1; You are taking the text from this [link](http://www.softwaredevelopersworld.com/java/serialization/serialization.php) without referencing it anywhere. If you cite text then make that clear!

Answer (score 1):

The [Java serialization format is standardized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html). Any JVM can write and read it.

The byte streams might be slightly different (for example, serializers might write some objects in a different order; if you have two `int` fields in a class, it doesn't matter in which order they are written).

But the result of deserializing will always be the same unless you changed the Java code of the classes that are stored in the byte stream.